# Way to match number patterns in Python

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and I wanted to know if there's a way to use conditional statements based on number patterns. For example if I have a list of numeric values such as:

```
583201
584068
485027
581047
```

And I was outputting a value to the variable "x" based on these numbers, how would I assign a value of 1 to all values starting with "58"?

I tried this:

```
import re

def Classify(SIC12):
   if re.search(7389*,SIC12):
       return 1
   else:
       return 0
```

But it looks like the search function only works for strings. Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: Convert the int to a string.  `str(SIC12)`, then use a regex

Comment: You could just convert the numbers to a string and use a regex on them with `re.search(r'58\d*', str(SIC12))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert the numbers to strings with str():

```
def classify(number):
    num_str = str(number)
    if num_str.startswith("58"):
        return 1
    return 0
```

For more complicated test cases, you might need to use regular expressions, but you can accomplish you specific example without them (not sure if that's preferable).

**EDIT:** Removed some wildly inappropriate semicolons.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow (I have to leave and I don't have access at home). Thanks so much!

Comment: Whoever downvoted, can you provide me with any insight as to why, please? I definitely get plenty of stuff wrong, but I'd like to be able to correct it if I can, and in this case I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: I decided to go back to my office and run it and it worked! Thanks a lot! I have no idea who downvoted you, I wish I had enough rep to give you an upvote.